# Kali Hotspot with Internet access thru proxy

Tags: iptables, kali-linux, hotspot, hostapd

I have a question.

My Kali laptop is only have access to the internet with a proxy (username, password, serverip an Port). Now i configured a Hotspot with Hostapd and I want to use the Internet with the mobile devices connected with the Hotspot.

How can I change the IPTable in that way, that it work.

I'm a beginner in Linux and IPTables.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Start
# Configure IP address for WLAN
sudo ifconfig wlan0 10.0.0.1
# Start DHCP/DNS server
sudo service dnsmasq restart
# Enable routing
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
# Enable NAT
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.0.0.1/24 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
# Run access point daemon
sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd.conf
```

I know I need to add the Server IP with Username and password, but I don't have a clue how to do this.

Thank you for all your help and sorry for my english.

Greetings